# Get-ADComputer returns different properties between Server 2019 and Windows 10

Tags: powershell, active-directory

If I run this PowerShell command under a Server 2019 OS

```
Get-ADComputer $CompName -Properties * | Get-Member | ft -AutoSize
```

I get the following list of properties and methods

```
Name                                 MemberType            Definition
----                                 ----------            ----------
Contains                             Method                bool Contains(string propertyName)
Equals                               Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetEnumerator                        Method                System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()
GetHashCode                          Method                int GetHashCode()
GetType                              Method                type GetType()
ToString                             Method                string ToString()
Item                                 ParameterizedProperty Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
AccountExpirationDate                Property              System.DateTime AccountExpirationDate {get;set;}
accountExpires                       Property              System.Int64 accountExpires {get;set;}
AccountLockoutTime                   Property              System.DateTime AccountLockoutTime {get;set;}
AccountNotDelegated                  Property              System.Boolean AccountNotDelegated {get;set;}
AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption    Property              System.Boolean AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption {get;set;}
AuthenticationPolicy                 Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
AuthenticationPolicySilo             Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
BadLogonCount                        Property              System.Int32 BadLogonCount {get;}
badPasswordTime                      Property              System.Int64 badPasswordTime {get;set;}
badPwdCount                          Property              System.Int32 badPwdCount {get;set;}
CannotChangePassword                 Property              System.Boolean CannotChangePassword {get;set;}
CanonicalName                        Property              System.String CanonicalName {get;}
Certificates                         Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
CN                                   Property              System.String CN {get;}
codePage                             Property              System.Int32 codePage {get;set;}
CompoundIdentitySupported            Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
countryCode                          Property              System.Int32 countryCode {get;set;}
Created                              Property              System.DateTime Created {get;}
createTimeStamp                      Property              System.DateTime createTimeStamp {get;}
Deleted                              Property              System.Boolean Deleted {get;}
Description                          Property              System.String Description {get;set;}
DisplayName                          Property              System.String DisplayName {get;set;}
DistinguishedName                    Property              System.String DistinguishedName {get;set;}
DNSHostName                          Property              System.String DNSHostName {get;set;}
DoesNotRequirePreAuth                Property              System.Boolean DoesNotRequirePreAuth {get;set;}
dSCorePropagationData                Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
Enabled                              Property              System.Boolean Enabled {get;set;}
HomedirRequired                      Property              System.Boolean HomedirRequired {get;set;}
HomePage                             Property              System.String HomePage {get;set;}
instanceType                         Property              System.Int32 instanceType {get;}
IPv4Address                          Property              System.String IPv4Address {get;}
IPv6Address                          Property              System.String IPv6Address {get;}
isCriticalSystemObject               Property              System.Boolean isCriticalSystemObject {get;set;}
isDeleted                            Property              System.Boolean isDeleted {get;}
KerberosEncryptionType               Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
LastBadPasswordAttempt               Property              System.DateTime LastBadPasswordAttempt {get;}
LastKnownParent                      Property              System.String LastKnownParent {get;}
lastLogoff                           Property              System.Int64 lastLogoff {get;set;}
lastLogon                            Property              System.Int64 lastLogon {get;set;}
LastLogonDate                        Property              System.DateTime LastLogonDate {get;}
lastLogonTimestamp                   Property              System.Int64 lastLogonTimestamp {get;set;}
localPolicyFlags                     Property              System.Int32 localPolicyFlags {get;set;}
Location                             Property              System.String Location {get;set;}
LockedOut                            Property              System.Boolean LockedOut {get;set;}
logonCount                           Property              System.Int32 logonCount {get;set;}
ManagedBy                            Property              System.String ManagedBy {get;set;}
MemberOf                             Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
MNSLogonAccount                      Property              System.Boolean MNSLogonAccount {get;set;}
Modified                             Property              System.DateTime Modified {get;}
modifyTimeStamp                      Property              System.DateTime modifyTimeStamp {get;}
ms-Mcs-AdmPwd                        Property              System.String ms-Mcs-AdmPwd {get;set;}
ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime          Property              System.Int64 ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime {get;set;}
msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes        Property              System.Int32 msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes {get;set;}
msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed   Property              System.Int32 msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed {get;}
Name                                 Property              System.String Name {get;}
nTSecurityDescriptor                 Property              System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity nTSecuri...
ObjectCategory                       Property              System.String ObjectCategory {get;}
ObjectClass                          Property              System.String ObjectClass {get;set;}
ObjectGUID                           Property              System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0...
objectSid                            Property              System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier objectSid {g...
OperatingSystem                      Property              System.String OperatingSystem {get;set;}
OperatingSystemHotfix                Property              System.String OperatingSystemHotfix {get;set;}
OperatingSystemServicePack           Property              System.String OperatingSystemServicePack {get;set;}
OperatingSystemVersion               Property              System.String OperatingSystemVersion {get;set;}
PasswordExpired                      Property              System.Boolean PasswordExpired {get;set;}
PasswordLastSet                      Property              System.DateTime PasswordLastSet {get;set;}
PasswordNeverExpires                 Property              System.Boolean PasswordNeverExpires {get;set;}
PasswordNotRequired                  Property              System.Boolean PasswordNotRequired {get;set;}
PrimaryGroup                         Property              System.String PrimaryGroup {get;}
primaryGroupID                       Property              System.Int32 primaryGroupID {get;set;}
PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion      Property              System.Boolean ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion {get;set;}
pwdLastSet                           Property              System.Int64 pwdLastSet {get;set;}
SamAccountName                       Property              System.String SamAccountName {get;set;}
sAMAccountType                       Property              System.Int32 sAMAccountType {get;set;}
sDRightsEffective                    Property              System.Int32 sDRightsEffective {get;}
ServiceAccount                       Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
servicePrincipalName                 Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
ServicePrincipalNames                Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
SID                                  Property              System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier SID {get;set;}
SIDHistory                           Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
TrustedForDelegation                 Property              System.Boolean TrustedForDelegation {get;set;}
TrustedToAuthForDelegation           Property              System.Boolean TrustedToAuthForDelegation {get;set;}
UseDESKeyOnly                        Property              System.Boolean UseDESKeyOnly {get;set;}
userAccountControl                   Property              System.Int32 userAccountControl {get;set;}
userCertificate                      Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueColle...
UserPrincipalName                    Property              System.String UserPrincipalName {get;set;}
uSNChanged                           Property              System.Int64 uSNChanged {get;}
uSNCreated                           Property              System.Int64 uSNCreated {get;}
whenChanged                          Property              System.DateTime whenChanged {get;}
whenCreated                          Property              System.DateTime whenCreated {get;}
```

If I run the same command under a Windows 10 OS, I get a much shorter list.

```
Name               MemberType            Definition                                                                                     
----               ----------            ----------                                                                                     
Contains           Method                bool Contains(string propertyName)                                                             
Equals             Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                 
GetEnumerator      Method                System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()                                       
GetHashCode        Method                int GetHashCode()                                                                              
GetType            Method                type GetType()                                                                                 
ToString           Method                string ToString()                                                                              
Item               ParameterizedProperty Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection Item(string propertyName) {get;}
AddedProperties    Property              System.Collections.Generic.ICollection[string] AddedProperties {get;}                          
DistinguishedName  Property              string DistinguishedName {get;set;}                                                            
DNSHostName        Property              string DNSHostName {get;set;}                                                                  
Enabled            Property              bool Enabled {get;set;}                                                                        
ModifiedProperties Property              System.Collections.Generic.ICollection[string] ModifiedProperties {get;}                       
Name               Property              string Name {get;}                                                                             
ObjectClass        Property              string ObjectClass {get;set;}                                                                  
ObjectGuid         Property              System.Nullable[guid] ObjectGuid {get;set;}                                                    
PropertyCount      Property              int PropertyCount {get;}                                                                       
PropertyNames      Property              System.Collections.ICollection PropertyNames {get;}                                            
RemovedProperties  Property              System.Collections.Generic.ICollection[string] RemovedProperties {get;}                        
SamAccountName     Property              string SamAccountName {get;set;}                                                               
SID                Property              System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier SID {get;set;}                                    
UserPrincipalName  Property              string UserPrincipalName {get;set;}
```

I'm using the same AD login in both OSs. The server's PowerShell version is 5.1.17763.2931 and the Windows 10 PowerShell version is 5.1.19041.1682. All I want to do is return the computer description in the Win10. I can see it in ADUC while on Win10 but I can't get it in PowerShell. Is there another way to return the computer description other than Get-ADComputer? Better yet, is there a way to get all the properties in Win10?

Comment: You probably don't have the AD tools or PowerShell module loaded. Try `Add-WindowsCapability -Name Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 -Online` and `Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory`. Better yet, I bet you're piping the error that would explain this right into `Get-Member` try just the first part of your command. That's a very good first step in troubleshooting.

Comment: You should probably NOT be using `Format-Table` or `Get-Member`; use `Select-Object -Property *` instead

Comment: The RSAT tools are installed and I do have the ActiveDirectory module imported. I ran both commands again just to be sure. Also, it makes no difference if I use Get-Member or Select-Object. I get the same result.

Comment: for anyone who's looking at this in the future, i found another way to get the computer description from AD. [https://lazywinadmin.com/2013/10/powershell-get-domaincomputer-adsi.html](https://lazywinadmin.com/2013/10/powershell-get-domaincomputer-adsi.html) without using the powershell ActiveDirectory module